# spark splits a stage on “apply at Option.scala:120”

Tags: apache-spark, stage

When I run spark applications, I see from the web-ui that  some stage description are like “apply at Option.scala:120”. Why spark splits a stage on a line that is not in my spark program but a Scala library?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

These lines are generated in `Utils.getCallStack()` ([GitHub link](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/3f169bfe3c322bf4344e13276dbbe34279b59ad0/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/Utils.scala#L873)). Basically it's the method name (`apply` here) on the last Spark line in the stack trace plus the file name and line number (`Option.scala:120`) on the first non-Spark line in the stack trace.

So it looks like you make an `Option.getOrElse()` call, and the default value you provide is what starts the stage.

In Spark 1.1 you can get the full stack trace for each stage, taking out the guesswork from this.